# Como tener varios valores en una consulta de sql

Tags: mysql

tengo una base de datos y ocupo hacer una consulta que solo muestre varios datos y otros no.

Ejemplo.
Que de una tabla sacar los modelos de los autos, pero que no esten ciertas marcas,
como seria la consulta?

Comment: Hola, trata de profundizar mas lo que requieres... si deseas coloca una captura de la tabla que quieres traer y los campos

Comment: Esta es la consulta, consulta que muestre la cantidad de autos rentados y la suma del importe total de las rentas por marca de auto que NO sean Nissan ni Kia. Solo rentas que no esten canceladas y ordenado por marca

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la estructura de las tablas?

Comment: Francisco, pese a ser una pregutna simple es muy amplia. porque has de mostrar lo que has intentado. Una vez que lo intentes, si no te sale muestranos la consulta y el diseño de tabla asi como los errores o resultados  obtenidos. un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque sin más información es difícil dar una respuesta concreta, a modo de ejemplo, en una tabla llamada coches, que tiene, entre otros possibles, los campos modelo, marca y precio, una consulta podría ser:

```
SELECT modelo, precio FROM coches
WHERE marca NOT IN ('Opel', 'Seat', 'Mercedes')
```

Esta consulta selecciona el modelo y precio de todos los registros de la tabla que su marca no es ni Opel ni Seat ni Mercedes.